# How to predict both category and sub category in machine learning classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, multilevel-analysis, multi-class, multilabel

There are 4 actions available. Each action has its own varying number of categories.
The target is to predict an action along with the category of action, given input data.

Assume actions are a,b,c,d
Assume categories:
(1)under a: a1,a2,a3,a4.
(2)under b: b1,b2.
(3)under c: c1.
(4)under d:d1.

Example prediction:1)( action a, category a3)
(2)(action b, category b2)

I have used a multi label model to predict the action part. But can't figure out how to do the category part. Maybe with some hierarchical classification method.

Comment: Why not just predict the category directly? Say "Action A and category 3"?

Comment: @user2974951 how do you propose to do that, given categories are unique to action type. Segregate all categories based on each action and train a classifier model for it? This would result in 5 models. One for action and one for category under each of 4 actions

Comment: No, if you have 3 actions and 4 categories, then you create 3*4=12 labels for each possible outcome, and predict these.

Comment: @user2974951 I think the issue is that predicting $a_1$ when the correct answer is $a_2$ is not as bad as predicting an $a_2$ as some kind of $b$. An example of this could be predicting a golden retriever as a German shepherd. That’s the wrong type of dog, but at least you predicted a dog and not a cat!

Comment: @Dave exactly!!

Answer (score 0):

With neural networks, you would do this by having multiple outputs:

- the (logit)-probability of being in each category from **a** to **d** (that's the easy bit with not too many choices)

AND one of the following options (at least these two make sense):

- the (logit)-probability of being in each category-subcategory combination (i.e. falling into **a1,a2,a3,a4, b1,b2, c1** or **d1**) treating these are a separate categorical problem to the first one:

  - downside: does not enforce that the probability of being in **a1** to **a4** adds up to the probability of being in **a**.
  - It also sort of double-counts categories **c** and **d**, where there's really no sub-category.
  - It's very straightforward to implement though.
- the (logit)-probability of being in sub-category **1** to **4** conditional on being in category **a** and the (logit)-probability of being in sub-category **1** or **2** conditional on being in category **b**:

  - enforces the constraints (you can also output the outputs of the above, but internally set-up the model like this, it's really the same thing).
  - As a loss function, you would not incur any loss for the first output when the category is **b**, **c** or **d**, but use categorical crossentropy for the choice of **1** to **4** when the category is **a**.
  - Similarly, the loss function of the second target would only apply a loss function when the category is **b**.

With things other than neural networks, it's hard to do it all in a single model. However, you could have sequential models (i.e. first one that predicts the category and then for categories **a** and **b** two models that predict the subcategory). These, would only be trained on the subset of observations in category **a** and **b**.